# Jquery click on a div show this, click anywhere except this hide div?

Tags: jquery, click, hide, show

I have two div, 1st is hidden(real), 2nd is shown(fake).

Question:
Click on 1st div hide 1st div, show 2nd div
and click on document.body except 2nd div > hide 2nd div, show 1st div
?

here it is:

```
$(".fake").click(function () {
    $(".fake").hide();
    $(".real").show();
});
$(document.body).click.**except(".real")**.(function () {
    $(".fake").show();
    $(".real").hide();
});
```

Like this :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document.body).not(".real").click.(function () {
    $(".fake").show();
    $(".real").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target` too:

```
$(document.body).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.is('.real')) { return false; }
    $(".fake").show();
    $(".real").hide();
});
```